# Rails: remove reference relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relationship, migrate

I was confused with following code in tutorial.

The goal is to remove reference key `genre_id` from table `books`

```
class RemoveGenreFromBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def up
        remove_index :books, column: [:genre_id]
        remove_column :books, :genre_id
    end

    def down
        add_reference :books, :genre, index: true
    end

end
```

But I don't understand what `remove_index :books, column: [:genre_id]` mean

Furthermore, I didn't get that `index: true` in `down` method.

If I need to add a relationship, why I can not just type

```
class Addrelationship < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
            add_reference :books, :genre
    end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As there is a method to add a referecen, there is a one to remove also - `remove_reference`

Syntax is: `remove_reference(table_name, ref_name, options = {})`

So in your case, to remove the reference of `Genre` :

```
class RemoveGenreFromBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_reference :books, :genre, index:true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

The option `foreign_key: true` will also remove the foreign key from the `books` table.

Answer (score 0):

rake db:rollback STEP=1

Is a way to do this, if the migration you want to rollback is the last one applied. You can substitute 1 for however many migrations you want to go back.

Comment: Does `rake db:rollback` rollback the last one migration by default?

Comment: STEP=1, STEP=2 and so on is the steps you want to roll back your migrations.

Comment: actually, I was confused that why I need to type `up` and `down` method instead of typing `change` method to rollback `add_reference` migration

Comment: I have changed question title, the point I want to know is `column: [:genre_id]` and `index: true` in `up` and `down` method relatively